# How can i make menu boot windows and ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, windows-8

Sorry my english is not good, my laptop has installed windows 8.1. Then I installed ubuntu 12.04, so now I cant access windows 8.1. When I turned my laptop on, I dont have any menu boot. How can I log in windows 8.1?
Thanks ^^

Comment: So , when you turn on laptop , it goes where ? to Windows or Ubuntu ? Also, read answer here, especially troubleshooting part: http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/295286

Answer (score 0):

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair, you can choose the second option to install Root Repair in Ubuntu by running the following commands in a terminal within Ubuntu:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo sed 's/trusty/saucy/g' -i /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yannubuntu-ubuntu-boot-repair-trusty.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

The link above also has instructions on how to use it, but the easiest way is just to open Boot Repair and then click [Recommended Repair].

Hopefully this should get you up and running with a dual boot.